# simple deform modifier not working properly

Tags: modifiers

I have some problem using the simple deform modifier, for some reason it doesn't rotate on the z axis making a circle but it does the stuff in the image

[image]

Comment: It does rotate here... but for what I imagine you want to do, rotate the mesh in Z around its origin in edit mode so that it is oriented along X.

Comment: I would like to make a ring, a circle

Comment: I followed this video but instead of getting the circle he have I get this strange shape

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlnkGCdtGEw

Comment: Yes, as I've said previously, he constructs the wall along X, and you're doing it along Y.

Comment: I'm gonna do It along x but is there anyway to do that on y axis?

Comment: Yes, you can add an origin object at the same center and rotate it 90 around z so that its X is along your Y.

Comment: I always use Simple Deform with an arrows Empty as axis/origin, to make sense of it.

Comment: I'm gonna give a try

Comment: I works if I do that along x axis, I didn't understand how to do that on the y, I want to understand that just because I find annoying every time to remember to do stuff along x instead of y, btw thanks, I will try to fix on the y later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bend simple modifier rotates an axis around the specified one in the modifier.

When Z is chosen, the X axis is bent:

[image]

That why you have the result indicated in your question when all is aligned along Y.

If you want to keep things along Y, though, you can add a deformation origin object (an empty) and rotate 90 degrees it so that its X is align along Y:

[image]

Comment: I  Always use _'Simple' Deform_ in Z, with a helper Empty. I can't be bothered to remember the other axes..